# SELECT Permission denied on table when stored procedure has execute permission

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting the following error when trying to run a stored procedure:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'tblMarketContact_Type_link', database 'FMS', schema 'Marketing'.

The stored procedure was running fine before I included this table. It has execute permissions for the database role it is being ran under. It uses dynamic SQL.

I am guessing it has something to do with the stored procedure being in a separate schema from the table? The stored procedure is just in the dbo schema.

What is the best way to fix this? I would think simply granting select permissions on this table for the security role would be an easy fix, but I want to avoid that. I'd like for only the stored procedure to have permission to execute and select from that table.

Comment: Grant permissions on the table or don't reference it in dynamic SQL. Ownership chaining doesn't work for dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I don't recall ever having to do that before but there's a good chance select permissions already existed on the other tables.

Comment: To  be clear ownership chaining will still work for the non dynamic SQL parts of the proc. It is only the dynamic SQL parts that will cause this.

Comment: Adding that with static SQL, the owners of the proc and table schemas will need to be the same to avoid ownership chain issues.

Comment: If granting permission on the table is unsavory for whatever reason, [module signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-ver16) is also an option.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Grant statement on a role an use that role to execute a stored procedure like

```
Create Role xyz;

Grant execute on "your_stored_procedure_name" to newrole;
```

If you don't want to use a new role, then you can use grant statement for a particular schema.

```
Grant select on "your stored procedure name" to "user";
```